# AOP: A combination of two @annotation clauses is not working

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I'm trying to write a pointcut, which shall hit for every method marked with certain annotation except the ones marked with another annotation.
But the following is not working:

```
<aop:aspect ref="...">
        <aop:before method="execute" pointcut="@annotation(MyAnnotation1) 
                  and not @annotation(MyAnnotation2)"/>
</aop:aspect>
```

Will you please advise what i'm doing wrong?..

Comment: What do you mean by _is not working_?

Comment: I mean that methods annotated by both MyAnnotation1 and MyAnnotation2 are still covered by pointcut, while they should not

Answer (score 1):

The [Spring AOP documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-schema-pointcuts) states

> When combining pointcut sub-expressions, `&&` is awkward within an XML
>   document, and so the keywords `and`, `or` and `not` can be used in place of
>   `&&`, `||` and `!` respectively.

However, you're not allowed to bind parameters with negation. If you're saying it doesn't exist, what value would be passed as an argument?

Change it to

```
<aop:before method="execute" pointcut="@annotation(MyAnnotation1) 
                  and not @annotation(com.example.MyAnnotationName)"/>
```

So `MyAnnotation1` can refer to a parameter, but the other can't. As such, you need to specify the fully qualified name of the annotation type. A corresponding pointcut would look like

```
//@Pointcut(value = "@annotation(MyAnnotation1) && !@annotation(com.example.MyAnnotationName)")
public void yesNotNo(MyAnnotation1 MyAnnotation1) {
}
```